# How do I populate a spinner inside spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(...)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As the title puts my query, I want to populate my spinner only when the user clicks it i.e., the spinner will initially be empty, when the user clicks it then and only then should all the items show. I tried out the following code:

```
if (spin1 != null) {
     spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
         arr.add("Hello");
         arr.add("Hey");
         arr.add("Yo");
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr);
         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         assert spin1 != null;
         spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
    });
}
```

But my above code is not working. The spinner is empty when I click on it. Can you please tell me why and how to fix this issue?

Comment: You are setting **OnItemSelectedListener** so when there is no any item, it's not invoked I think. Did you try setting **OnClickListener** instead?

Comment: yea it throws an error. Inface `onClickListener` isn't allowed on spinners.

Answer (score 0):

You can register `TouchListener` to set `Adapter` for the `Spinner` on the first click like in the code snippet shown below:

```
// array list to populate the spinner's item
List < String > array = new ArrayList < > ();
array.add("Nepal");
array.add("India");
array.add("China");

// create adapter instance from the array list
ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < > (requireContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// register on item selected listener as usual
binding.testSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), array.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent) {}
});

// set on touch listener as we cant set onclick listener in spinner
// because it is made to throw exception
binding.testSpinner.setOnTouchListener((v, event) - > {
    // set the adapter in the touch event
    // ACTION_UP occurs when user releases the finger
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        binding.testSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    // return false as we dont want to consume the event
    // but want to allow it to propagate in the parent view hierarchy
    return false;
});
```